# "Had left" or "left "

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

Can we use this sentence:

> He hadn't talked to his parents since he left school.

instead of this one:

> He hadn't talked to his parents since he **had** left school.

Comment: Hi I see you have asked some questions but have accepted no answers. Please consider upvoting and accepting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible, but the simple past ("since he left") is more common.

When the temporal relationships are clear without it, and there is no narrative or rhetorical reason to set a temporal focus, English speakers often use the simple past (*left*) when the past perfect could also be used (*had left*)